# Contract Deployment "not enough funds for gas" Arbitrum

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, arbitrum

I am trying to deploy a contract using the following code:

```js
 const Contract = await ethers.getContractFactory("Contract", {
    libraries: {
      UtilsLibrary: "0xF...e",
    }
 });
let pool = await Contract.deploy({gasLimit: 10000000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", "gwei")})
```

When I run this on Kovan, Goerly, Arbitrum Goerly, this works totally fine (obviously I correct the library address). When I run this on the Arbitrum mainnet I get an error saying "not enough funds for gas". I have changed multiple RPCs and result is not luck.

Contract takes about 5 mil gas to deploy and I have about 1 ETH in wallet. I really have no more ideas on what might be wrong here. Any suggestions appreciated.

UPD: I have deployed the UtilsLibrary totally fine as part of the script as well. So the correct signer is being used and it has funds.....

Answer (score 0):

I had to increase the gas limit to 100mil and it took 80 mil to deploy. I am not sure why similar transaction only took 5mil on kovan and Arbitrum testnet

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrum has a different way to compute gas cost, see here https://developer.offchainlabs.com/docs/Differences_Overview#fee-stats

In particular, `calldata` is more expensive than L1, and this explains the  contract deployment extra cost.